# What is $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{(8n+1)(3n+4)}$?

Tags: sequences-and-series

How can we evaluate $\sum_{n\ge1}\frac{1}{(8n+1)(3n+4)}$? The $n$th term is $\frac{8}{29}\frac{1}{8n+1}-\frac{3}{29}\frac{1}{3n+4}$. Then what process should I follow?

Comment: what's the context here, is this a homework question? is it possible you were asked to check whether it converges instead of evaluating?

Comment: If you want to evaluate it, by the way, [you can](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=sum+from+n%3D1+to+infinity+1%2F%28%288n%2B1%29%283n%2B4%29%29), but I can't imagine it will be in any sense pleasant.

Comment: it converges to 0.0347 but I want to know the integral process to sum the series.

Comment: If you would like to replace summation by integration, you should include this in the question.

Comment: $\frac1{29}\left(H_{4/3}-H_{1/8}\right)$

Answer (score 4):

The difference between two digamma functions may be expressed as

$$ \psi(x)-\psi(y) = (x-y)\sum_{j=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(j+x)(j+y)}$$

Let

$$ S = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(8n+1)(3n+4)}$$

Hence

$$S =\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(8n+1)(3n+4)} + \frac{1}{4}-\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{24}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(n+\frac{1}{8})(n+\frac{4}{3})}-\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{24}\left[-\frac{24}{29}\left(\psi\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)\right)\right]-\frac{1}{4} = \frac{1}{29}\left(\psi\left(\frac{4}{3}\right)-\psi\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{4}$$

It is possible to evaluate the digamma function for any rational $\displaystyle x=\frac{m}{n}$

Using the formula

$$\psi\left(\frac{1}{3}+J\right) +\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}} = -\gamma -\ln\sqrt{27} + \sum_{j=1}^{J} \frac{3}{3j-2} \quad J=0,1,2,..$$

with $J=1$

$$\psi\left(\frac{4}{3}\right) = -\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}}-\gamma -\ln\sqrt{27} + 3$$

$\displaystyle\psi\left(\frac{1}{8}\right)$ is a little bit more difficult but can be evaluated with the following formula:

$$\psi\left(\frac{m}{n}\right) = -\gamma -\frac{\pi}{2}\cot\left(\frac{m\pi}{n}\right) + 2 \sum_{j=1}^{J}\left[\cos\left(\frac{2jm\pi}{n}\right) \ln\left( 2\sin\left(\frac{j\pi}{n}\right)\right)\right]-\begin{cases} \ln(2n) \quad n=2J+2 =2,4,6,... \\ \ln(n) \quad n=2J+1=3,5,7,... \end{cases}$$

$$\psi\left(\frac{1}{8}\right) = -\gamma -\frac{\pi}{2}\cot\left(\frac{\pi}{8}\right) + 2 \sum_{j=1}^{3}\left[\cos\left(\frac{2j\pi}{8}\right) \ln\left( 2\sin\left(\frac{j\pi}{8}\right)\right)\right]-\ln(16) = -\gamma -\frac{\pi}{2}(1+\sqrt{2}) + \sqrt{2}\ln\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)-4\ln(2)$$

Therefore

$$ \boxed{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{(8n+1)(3n+4)}= \frac{1}{29}\left(-\frac{\pi}{2\sqrt{3}} -\ln\sqrt{27} + 3  +\frac{\pi}{2}(1+\sqrt{2}) - \sqrt{2}\ln\left(\sqrt{2}-1\right)+4\ln(2) \right)-\frac{1}{4}\approx 0.03470547873...}$$